General solution to first order linear difference / recurrence equations
Recently, in learning about difference equations, I've found that they're impressively similar to differential equations (Variation of constants, solution to equations with constant coefficients, superposition, ...).
The general first-order linear differential equation can be solved via an integrating factor:
$$ y' + a(x)y = b(x) $$
$$ \implies exp(\int a)b(x) = exp(\int a)y' + a(x)exp(\int a) $$
$$ \vdots $$
$$ y(x) = \frac{1}{exp(\int a)} (C + \int b \cdot exp(\int a)) $$
The general first-order linear difference equation is
$$ y_{n+1} + a_ny_n = b_n $$
I was wondering if a similar approach can solve this equation, but I haven't been able to find any general solutions.
Does an explicit formula exist?
$\large \text{My (unsuccessful) attempt}$
$exp(x)$ is so useful in the continuous case because $exp'(x) = exp(x)$. The discrete analogue is $\large 2^n$:
$$ \Delta 2^n = 2^{n + 1} - 2^n = 2^n $$
or, more generally,
$$ \Delta (\lambda + 1)^n = (\lambda + 1)(\lambda + 1)^n - (\lambda + 1)^n = (\lambda + 1 - 1)(\lambda + 1)^n = \lambda \cdot (\lambda + 1)^n$$
similarly to $\frac{d}{dx}e^{ax} = ae^{ax}$.
To make use of that, we need to rewrite our equation in terms of $\Delta y$:
$$ y_{n+1} + a_ny_n = b_n $$
$$y_{n+1} - y_n + y_n(a_n + 1) = b_n $$
$$\Delta y_n + y_n(a_n + 1) = b_n $$
For now, we'll focus on
$$ \Delta y_n + a_ny_n = b_n $$
I believe I'd have to find a "summation"-factor of the form $2^{q_n}$, but I haven't been able to figure out what exactly.
I also tried plugging into the aforementioned general formula for differential equations, replacing $\int$ with $\sum$ and $\frac{d}{dt}$ with $\Delta$, but the result wasn't a solution to the difference equation.
Does anyone know how such an approach could lead to the solution, or more generally, if a general solution exists?

A general solution exists, see here : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_first-order_non-homogeneous_recurrence_relations_with_variable_coefficients.

To compare with the continuous case you should consider the difference equation
$$ (y_{n+1} - y_n) + a_n \, y_n = b_n \, ,$$
i.e. replace your $a_n$ by $a_n - 1$. For a given $y_0$ the unique solution is
\begin{align*}
y_n = \hphantom{+}&(1-a_0) (1-a_1)(1-a_2) \cdots (1-a_{n-1}) y_0 \\
     +&\hphantom{(1-a_0)} (1-a_1)(1-a_2) \cdots (1-a_{n-1}) b_0 \\
     +&\hphantom{(1-a_0) (1-a_1)}(1-a_2) \cdots (1-a_{n-1}) b_1 \\
     & \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \vdots \\
     +&\hphantom{(1-a_0) (1-a_1)(1-a_2) \cdots (1-a_{n-1})} b_{n-1}
\end{align*}
and one can see that this is just a discretized version of
$$ y(x) = e^{-\int_0^x a(x') \mathrm{d}x'}y(0) + \int_0^x e^{-\int_{x'}^x a(x'') \mathrm{d}x''}b(x')\mathrm{d}x' \, . $$
For example, one replaces
$$ 
    e^{-\int_0^x a(x') \mathrm{d}x'} \rightarrow e^{- (a_0+\cdots+a_{n-1})} = (1-a_0) \cdots (1-a_{n-1}) + O(a^2). 
$$
To make the analogy perfect you could introduce a stepsize $\Delta x$ and consider the finite difference equation
$$ \frac{y_{n+1} - y_n}{\Delta x} + a_n \, y_n = b_n \, .$$
For $\Delta x \rightarrow 0$ you can then recover the continuous case (with $y_n$ corresponding to $y(n \,\Delta x)$ and analogously for $a$ and $b$).
